# I was added as a colaborator to a github repo, how do i make that repo show on my profile for publc?

Tags: github

me and my friends worked on this project and he added it in the end through his github. I'm fairly new to the platform so how do I show proof of contribution

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can see the contributors list for a repo in right side on repo page:[image]